# Is hitting a web-service costlier than invoking an equivalent JAR

Tags: java, spark-java

I am developing a new application, and want to know which approach will do better in performance-wise. Web service(let's say its running on spark-java) or its equivalent standalone JAR.

Comment: You could try creating a bare-bones version of both and see.

Comment: Assuming both do the same operation, the web service will incur additional cost (connection, data (de-)serializing, data transmission etc.).

Comment: If you mean including the jar as a library vs adding a network call to that jar behind a web server using it as a library should be faster but test it. If you want to call the other jar as an external process you will be paying the JVM warmup cost on every invocation.

Comment: Time to invoke methods (once jitted) is in the nanosecond range. Network latency is rarely less than tens of milliseconds. So yes: network calls are *expensive* (hence the guidance to avoid busy APIs when networks have to be crossed).

Comment: thanks guys, I'll keep it in mind :)